# Retrieving user's calendar events in Microsoft graph using application permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to build a small application that can retrieve a particular user's calendar events without a signed in user, that is to utilize the application permissions in Graph API and query the events by authenticating with App ID, Tenant ID and Secret values. I was able to follow this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service and generate JWT tokens to query the graph API. And it worked fine when i tried to retrieve all the users information, or even retrieve a particular users information using the following [paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request).

```
/users

/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

Both the above endpoints worked fine and i was able to retrieve details, but when i tried to access the calendar events of a particular user using the following Graph API [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

```
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events
```

I get the following error,

[image: Error when trying to retrieve particular users calendar events]

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here, i have the following Application permissions set up in Azure AD Portal and the permissions are reflected in the JWT token.

[image: Permissions in Azure AD portal]

[image: Permissions in JWT token]

I feel like the token generation part is working fine since the first two Graph API endpoints i mentioned above are functional, but I'm not sure where else I'm going wrong and as to why I'm not able to retrieve a particular user's calendar events. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you inspected the token at e.g. https://jwt.ms and verified the permissions are in the token? Your approach and config seems to be correct.

Comment: Hi @juunas thank you for the reply, yes i did verify that, ive updated the question with a screenshot of the permissions in my token.

Comment: To me it definitely looks like you should be able to read the calendar events with that token. And just to be 100% sure, this user has an Office 365 Outlook and Calendar in this AAD tenant?

Comment: I'm positive it does, since when i use the graph explorer and login with the same user Credentials, and try to access the exact same (/events) endpoint I'm able to retrieve the calendar events. Im guessing the graph explorer uses delegated permissions while im trying to use application permissions. But i'm a beginner to Azure AD and Graph API so i might've missed something, is there a way to check if the AAD tenant is properly connected to outlook and calendar?, I'm using my personal test account and this is not a live production account so there might be some configurations missing perhaps.

Comment: Your configuration definitely seems okay to me. And if you are getting back data with delegated permissions in Graph Explorer, it just shows that it should work. I'm honestly thinking this is an actual problem in MS Graph API right now.. (or somehow related to the account used, not allowing app-only access..)

Comment: Did you have a retry with creating a new Azure AD application and repeating all the configurations?

Comment: Hi @AllenWu, thank you, yes i did try redoing the steps multiple times with new Azure AD applications, the problem seems to persist, im thinking maybe something wrong with my account, i will try to do it in another account and see.

Comment: @KeshavKumaresan Any updates? The same issue for other accounts?